# YUM failing install; not recognizing JDK

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, jdk

I am attempting to install some packages using YUM. 
The command I am using is:

`sudo yum repo-pkgs [my repo] install`

This produces the following result:

```
 Error: Package: [package name] ([my repo])
       Requires: jdk >= 2000:1.8.0
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This error is confounding because I already have a JDK installed in `/user/java/jdk1.8.0_25`, which should be a sufficiently new version according to the error message.

Is there something I need to do to get YUM to recognize the JDK?

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: How did you install the JDK in `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25`?

Comment: I'm not sure...I am using a VM that had the JDK already installed there. Do you think I should try uninstalling it and then reinstalling a new JDK RPM package from Oracle?

Comment: Not necessarily. What is the output of `which java`? If it shows a valid binary in `/usr/jva/jdk1.8.0_25`, what is the output of `rpm -qf ${binary}` where ${binary} is the output of the `which` command?

Comment: Alternately, what does `rpm -qa | grep jdk` show?

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting help. `which java` returns `/usr/bin/java` rather than a location within the `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25` directory. `rpm -qf /usr/bin/java` prints that `java` is not owned by any package. `rpm -qa | grep jdk` prints `jdk1.8.0_25-1.8.0_25-fcs.x86_64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arthur stated, the problem is the disconnect between what's on the system and what's in the RPMDB. While the RPMDB does indeed have a JDK that it knows is installed, that JDK may not satisfy the package dependencies of the package you're attempting to install - in fact it definitely does not or you wouldn't be getting the particular error message. Where you go from here will depend on how "clean" you want the solution to be (versus "quick").

You can, as @Arthur suggested, create a dummy package. This package should depend on `jdk`, and should provide `jdk 1.8.0` with an epoch of 2000 or greater. It should have no payload - not even symlinks, which is where @Arthur's suggestion breaks down.

You can also install your package with `--nodeps`, which is the quick-and-dirty solution, but that may lead to dependency issues down the road if you have additional packages that depend on the current one or if you attempt to update it.

Finally, as our discussion ended up finding out, you can change the Requires: line in the specfile, since you're the one building this package and putting it in your repo.

Comment: To answer your last sentence, I would prefer a 'clean' solution ;)

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend building a dummy package with only a `Provides:` and no payload. That is the cleanest solution I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Great, thanks. I am new to RPM package creation. Should `Provides` be preceded by `jdk1.8.0_25`?

Comment: No. I would start with `Provides: jdk = 2000:1.8.0` in the specfile, though I may not have that syntax completely correct.

Comment: Alternately, since it looks like the package you're trying to isntall is coming from your repo, you can change the Requires line in that specfile so that it doesn't have the `2000` epoch value, which should then let it install without the shiv package. Sorry I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: That seems like a much better solution, but I will have to somehow get the authority to do so. The dummy spec is requiring a `Source:`, and won't let me leave that blank. How do you get around that?

Comment: Provide it a source. It doesn't have to be much, maybe just an empty tarball.

Comment: I ended up altering the `Requires` in the **original** `spec` lie you suggested. It listed `jdk => 2000:1.8.0`, so I simply added `_25` onto the end like so `jdk = 2000:1.8.0_25`. That ended up fixing the issue. I'll mark this answer as accepted, but add that bit about changing the specfile within the repo to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you have a JDK, but it is not in the **RPM database**, which is used by yum and other similar automatic package managers to know what packages are installed and get there respective versions.

The best solution may be running `sudo yum install jdk` so you can get a version with yum and rpm.

You can also consider following its suggestion to add the `--skip-broken` option, however it shares the problem with the second point in P.S.

Running the `rpm -Va` stuff may help RPM find missing packages and files. If you believe that you installed Java with RPM, try it.

P.S.: At first I considered creating a dummy package like what dpkg users may do, however:

1. It's quite complicated to make a package under RPM, since you will have to write a long spec. RPM also uses the file list to look for library dependencies, so you have to give it quite a long file list. 
   Possible workaround: Automatic `%files` generation with `find` and a lot of shell.
2. Even though you completed making a dummy package and installed it, your package is quite likely to be unable to find your java, if it uses some hard-encoded logic to navigate to the Java installed by the jdk package. (Most packagers don't use a weird directory like `/user`, and if you are unlucky enough to find a package written by a guy who doesn't know any `java_home` stuff…)
   Possible workaround: symlinking.

Update:

It seems that the package name of your JDK is `jdk1.8.0_25`. Since you already have one installed with RPM, it would be much easier and cleaner to create a dummy package, although it is still somehow a dirty hack.

Just write a spec for the package `jdk` of the reqired version, and make it depend on `jdk1.8.0_25`. Then add some symlinks to the `%files` block so your program can find it. Finally, really create the symlinks and do `rpmbuild -bb dummy_jdk.spec`.

Comment: It's actually quite simple to make a dummy RPM package, and point two doesn't come in to this matter since it's an RPM dependency, not a file dependency.

Comment: `sudo yum install jdk` simply prints `No package jdk available`. I had already tried that before. Additionally, `rpm -Va` seemed to help clean up things, but when I tried the install again it still failed with the same error. `--skip-broken` is what I have been using until now, but at this point I need that package.

Comment: @John Yes, you are right. However I'm not sure if scott is going to see some file deps afterwards… Anyway, with that `jdk1.8.0_25` package, the dummy one can be much cleaner.